# imagettftext(): Problem doing text layout error in PHP 7.3.18

Tags: php, imagettftext

I have a problem with `imagettftext()` function in PHP 7.3.

I am trying to generate a ticket. When I use text with PHP_EOL in the end of the text (example: `"some text"` . PHP_EOL), `imagettftext()` function can't work and generates

```
imagettftext(): Problem doing text layout
```

error.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What happens when you leave off the `.PHP_EOL`?

Comment: If I'll remove all PHP_EOL, the code works

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is a magic constant that depends on the environment but I cannot reproduce it with any EOL combination. Are you positively sure that having a line feed is the only factor? A short self-contained script would help a lot. (BTW, the error probably comes from [libgd](https://github.com/libgd/libgd/blob/master/src/gdft.c#L1417)).